# Null-safe Method invocation Java7

Tags: java, java-7

I want to get details about this feature of Java7 like this code

```
public String getPostcode(Person person)
{
    if (person != null)
    {
        Address address = person.getAddress();
        if (address != null)
        {
            return address.getPostcode();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Can be do something like this

```
public String getPostcode(Person person)
{
    return person?.getAddress()?.getPostcode();
}
```

But frankly its not much clear to me.Please explain?

Comment: Why do you need to write it in a shorter way? It's easy to read and straightforward in your first example.

Comment: @Kon yes right but who will not want to write small code

Comment: I think that proposal is rejected for Java 7. Do you have a link for the official documentation?

Comment: @c.s. check the question section someone given the link also i checked its somewhere else

Comment: Don't return null, if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Null-safe method invocation was proposed for Java 7 as a part of Project Coin, but it didn't make it to final release.

See all the proposed features, and what all finally got selected here - https://wikis.oracle.com/display/ProjectCoin/2009ProposalsTOC

---

As far as simplifying that method is concerned, you can do a little bit change:

```
public String getPostcode(Person person) {

    if (person == null) return null;
    Address address = person.getAddress();
    return address != null ? address.getPostcode() : null;
}
```

I don't think you can get any concise and clearer than this. IMHO, trying to merge that code into a single line, will only make the code less clear and less readable.

Comment: @subodh. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Do you mean this feature is not available with java7 and we can not implement it yet?

Comment: @subodh. Yes. Check that link in my answer. You will see what all features were added in Java 7

Comment: Hmm so do you mean if Java7 will have this type of feature it will increase complexity of coder

Comment: @subodh. Well, I'm not the right person to comment on this. I can't comment on why a feature was accepted, and why some were rejected. May be they felt it not so important to be added as an extra feature. May be this doesn't add much value to the language.

Comment: Why wouldn't just try/catching a NPE here be cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly and you want to make the code shorter, you could take advantage of short-circuit operators by writing:

```
if (person != null && person.getAddress() != null)
    return person.getAddress().getPostCode();
```

The second condition won't be checked if the first is false because the && operator short-circuits the logic when it encounters the first `false`.

Comment: Except you evaluate `person.getAddress()` twice :(

Comment: @Gamb No, it's not a question of optimization (although that could also come into play if `getAddress()` took a long time, but persumably it doesn't). This code is not the same as the OP's code.

Comment: @Gamb If `getAddress()`'s body involves substantial amounts of processing, a second call would be undesirable. Without knowing the method's implementation, we can't make assumptions about the optimization quality of one call versus two calls.

Comment: For the record, I would never write code like my answer here. I would prefer the code the OP wrote originally. But if his question is regarding a strictly shorter way of writing something, then my reply should be helpful in some way. HOPEFULLY.

Comment: @Vulcan I asked that before realizing the slight difference in the code. Still, if we can't assume in one way, we shouldn't be so hasty as to consider the other one more valid.

Comment: You're missing a last line: `return null;` (or `else return null;`)

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you:

```
public String getPostcode(Person person) {
    return person != null && person.getAddress() != null ? person.getAddress().getPostcode() : null;
}
```

Also check this thread: [Avoiding != null statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java)

Comment: @NotNull will supported by Java7

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid calling getAddress twice, you can do this:

```
Address address;
if (person != null && (address = person.getAddress()) != null){
      return address.getPostCode();
}
```